# Условный оператор не учитывает изменения условия

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

У меня есть React компонент, представляющий форму с инпутами (Текст, Числа, Дата). В инпуте даты есть значение по умолчанию - сегодня(`today`). Я использую один этот компонент для двух функций: создания объекта и для редактирования объекта. В первом случае все инпуты по умолчанию пустые, кроме инпута даты, в него предаётся значения `today`. Во втором случае, инпуты получают значение по умолчанию из опциональных пропсов(`values`), которые поступают в компонент из стейта родительского компонента. Компонент рендериться на странице в двух экземплярах, в один `values` передаются, в другой нет.
Поскольку наличие `values` опционально, я включил в дефолтные значения каждого импута условный оператор. В случае с импутом даты он выглядит так:

```
defaultValue={inputValues?.date ? inputValues.date : today}
```

В остальных случаях, вместо `today` ставится пустая строка `''`.

Я ожидал, что при изменении стейта, компонент будет ререндериться и вставлять в дефолт инпута, значения `values`.
На практике же, так происходит только с теми инпутами, которые по умолчанию пустые, а инпут с датой, всегда имеет значение `today`.

Через консоль я вижу, что при рендере компонента `inputValue` имеет значение undefiend (`useState` стоит с пустыми скобками), поэтому я по началу предположил, что `values` не успевают появится к моменту рендера. Однако при нажатии на кнопку редактирования, корректные `values` высвечиваются в консоли.
В моём понимании в этот момент, компонент должен ререндериться и подставить значение `values`, в соответствии с выражением `{inputValues?.date ? inputValues.date : today}`
Однако по факту, значение календарая = `today`, а значение всех остальных импутов = `values`. Если же в выражении заменить `today` на пустую строку, то при вызове функции редактирования, значение календаря в форме редактирования = `inputValues.date`, однако дефолтное значение в форме создания теперь пустое, т.к. `today` в этом случае не задан.

Такое поведение не исключительно для календаря, любой другой инпут ведёт себя таким же образом, если в выражении, заменить пустую строку на любое значение.
Буду очень рад, если объясните такое поведение и как его исправить.

Тестовый пример

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    export default function Parent() {
      const [values, setValues] = useState();
      const change = () => setValues({ name: 'name', date: '2023-11-28' });
      return (
        <Child values={values} change={change} />
      );
    }
    
    function Child({ values, change }) {
      console.log(values);
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <button type="button" onClick={change} >clickMe</button>
          <input type="text" defaultValue={values?.name ? values.name : ''} />
          <input type="date" defaultValue={values?.date ? values.date : '2023-11-20'} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Вместо такого пространного описания, лучше бы сделал тестовый пример где будет проявляться твоя проблема и показал его тут.

Comment: Сделал тестовый пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно - `defaultValue` ведет себя довольно странно.

Я пошарился по интернету - с такой проблемой столкнулся не только ты. В итоге предлагают вот такое "решение" проблемы. Нужно "проблемному" инпуту дать атрибут `key`, да такой, чтобы он менялся каждый раз при рендере. Т.о. элемент начинает реагировать на изменение стейта в его `defaultValue`.

```js
//    
function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState();
  const change = () => setValues({ name: 'name', date: '2023-11-28' });
  return (
    <Child values={values} change={change} />
  );
}
//
function Child({ values = {}, change }) {
  console.log(values);
  const v1 = values.name ? values.name : ''
  const v2 = values.date ? values.date : '2023-11-20'
  const k = v2 ? v2 : (new Date()).toString()
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button type="button" onClick={change} >clickMe</button>
      <input type="text" defaultValue={v1} />
      <input key={k} type="date" defaultValue={v2} />
    </div>
  );
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. 
Выглядит так, будто реакт ре-рендерит не весь компонент, а только те части, где он увидел изменения и ставя динамичный key, мы заставляем его ре-рендерить импут.

Comment: @Caplex, из того что прочитал про эту проблему - основной посыл такой, что  `defaultValue` для такого не предназначен. Если хочешь делать изменение значения поля "от некоего стейта" - используй `value` + `onChange`. Изменение `key` у элемента кагбэ говорит Реакту что это вообще новый элемент. Тогда старый реально удаляется и создается новый и с новым значением `defaultValue`.

Comment: Разумно, `defaultValue` подразумевает статичное значение, но непонятно как оно может сохраняться, если при ре-рендере значение вычисляется заново.
Ладно. Проблема решена. Спасибо.

Comment: @Caplex _как оно может сохраняться, если при ре-рендере значение вычисляется заново_ - точно также как сохраняется значение из useState